# SoapClient result "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed"

Tags: php, http, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to open a socket between my server and the other server, but it returns the following warring msg :

> SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

my SoapClient should be connected using a specific IP, so I'm using the following code:

> $aOpts = array('socket' => array('bindto' => 'my IP'));
> $rStreamContext = stream_context_create($aOpts);
>
> $client = new SoapClient($this->_wsdl_test_url, array('stream_context'=>$rStreamContext));

the server keep giving me the same warning, failed to open stream: HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it was fixed, the problem was with the encryption of the file, I put it UTF8 without BOM instead of UTF8